# Element event on canvas not firing

Tags: javascript, canvas, click

I have two div on canvas (see the [picture](http://uupload.ir/files/b0sl_canvas.png)) but event click does not firing
meanwhile when i change the position of elements to out of canvas event was working

[image: canvas]

Also I use gojs lib

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#graph-zoomin').click(function (e) {
        console.log(e.data);
        myDiagram.commandHandler.increaseZoom();
    });
    $('#graph-zoomout').click(function (e) {
        myDiagram.commandHandler.decreaseZoom();
    });
});
```

s

```
<div id='DiagramDiv' style='width:100%; height:650px; background-color: #DAE4E4;'><canvas tabindex="0" width="1175" height="650" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; z-index: 2; user-select: none; width: 1175px; height: 650px; cursor: auto;"></canvas></div>
<div id='graph-zoom'>
<div id='graph-zoomin'><i class='fa fa-plus'></i></div> 
<div id='graph-zoomout'><i class='fa fa-minus'></i></div>
</div>
```

Comment: could you please send the code where the divs are created?

Comment: @gabonator i'm edited the post

Comment: When you look into browser console, is anything shown when you click zoom-in button? You have there console.log and it seems that it should be working.

Comment: @gabonator No, there is nothing

Comment: Is it possible to post whole code?

Comment: @gabonator unfortunatly not

Comment: Use [chrome element inspector](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/inspect-styles/) to determine whether you are clicking on the right div

Comment: @gabonator  canvas element

Comment: great, so you have some canvas element on top of your zoom buttons. Try setting [zIndex](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp) on it to put it on top

Comment: @gabonator
That's worked my friend, Thank you for helping